# Spring Boot Configuration Class isn't Properly passing values from application.properties

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot

I'm creating a spring boot application with the AWS SDK. I am having some troubles with my S3 configuration class. I originally had all of the access keys and secrets keys stored in the code, and am transitioning to having an IAM user credentials in application.properties that has access to secrets manager, and getting all of the credentials for services through that. For some reason, the values are not properly populating. I believe it's possible that the constructor is executing before the value injection. Not sure on the best solution to fix this, thanks in advance for any help.

Here's the code for the S3 config class –

```
@Configuration
public class S3Config {

    private String accessKeyId;

    private String secretAccessKey;

    @Bean
    public AmazonS3 amazonS3Client(@Value("${aws.access-key-id}") String accessKeyId, @Value("${aws.secret-access-key") String secretAccessKey) {
        this.accessKeyId = accessKeyId;
        this.secretAccessKey = secretAccessKey;
        BasicAWSCredentials awsCredentials = getBasicAWSCredentials();
        return AmazonS3ClientBuilder
                .standard()
                .withRegion("xx")
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials))
                .build();
    }
    

    private BasicAWSCredentials getBasicAWSCredentials() {

            String secretName = "xx";
            String region = "xx";

            AWSSecretsManager client  = AWSSecretsManagerClientBuilder.standard()
                    .withRegion(region)
                    .withCredentials(
                            new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(
                                    new BasicAWSCredentials(
                                            accessKeyId,
                                            secretAccessKey
                                    )
                            )
                    )
                    .build();


            String secret = "";
            String decodedBinarySecret;
            GetSecretValueRequest getSecretValueRequest = new GetSecretValueRequest()
                    .withSecretId(secretName);
            GetSecretValueResult getSecretValueResult = null;

            try {
                getSecretValueResult = client.getSecretValue(getSecretValueRequest);
            } catch (DecryptionFailureException e) {
                // Secrets Manager can't decrypt the protected secret text using the provided KMS key.
                // Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
                throw e;
            } catch (InternalServiceErrorException e) {
                // An error occurred on the server side.
                // Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
                throw e;
            } catch (InvalidParameterException e) {
                // You provided an invalid value for a parameter.
                // Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
                throw e;
            } catch (InvalidRequestException e) {
                // You provided a parameter value that is not valid for the current state of the resource.
                // Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
                throw e;
            } catch (ResourceNotFoundException e) {
                // We can't find the resource that you asked for.
                // Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
                throw e;
            }

            if (getSecretValueResult.getSecretString() != null) {
                secret = getSecretValueResult.getSecretString();
            } else {
                decodedBinarySecret = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(getSecretValueResult.getSecretBinary()).array());
            }

            JsonObject secrets = new Gson().fromJson(secret, JsonObject.class);
            return new BasicAWSCredentials(secrets.get("accessKey").getAsString(), secrets.get("secretKey").getAsString());
    }
```

And here's an example of me using the S3 config in a service class. This was all working before I introduced the application.properties file and @Value annotations.

```
@Service
public class FileService {

    private AmazonS3 amazonS3Client;
    private String bucketName;
    private FileRepository fileRepository;

    public FileService(AmazonS3 amazonS3Client, FileRepository fileRepository) {
        this.amazonS3Client = amazonS3Client;
        bucketName = "xx";
        this.fileRepository = fileRepository;
    }
```

Comment: why don't you just use role based security? You don't have to access them in the code. In your case you are able to access the secrets manager somehow? What access key are you using for that? Why not give that "Role" access to S3?

Comment: The access key I'm using for the secrets manager is an IAM user that has access to only the secrets manager. And secrets manager stores all of the keys for each IAM user associated with S3, Dynamo, etc. I'm confused on what you are suggesting? Perhaps there is a better and more secure way to do this.

Comment: For the production version, I will give the EC2 instance access to secrets manager, which will then retrieve all of the IAM user credentials for each service. I just need to come up with a solution for local testing.

Comment: Why don't you just give the EC2 access to the various aws services the app needs? The strength of this approach is that is a role and not a user and thus does not even have an access key and secret (no credentials to protect).

Comment: I like this approach. How do I continue to build my app locally (testing with the actual AWS services), since it's not deployed on an EC2 instance yet?

Comment: so you put your access key and secret as env vars locally... see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/credentials.html and the "chain"... it looks in a _lot_ of places to find credentials. You can put them elsewhere if you like